# For large assets folder 'Uploading apk to device' takes too long every time

Tags: android, assets, uploading

I have a large file in my "assets" folder. Now every time when I run my application through eclipse, it copies the large file on the device. It takes too long in uploading file. I want to copy the large file on to the device only when it is changed and not every time. how to do that?

Comment: `every time when I run my application through eclipse, it copies the large file on the device`. It will do that too if the user starts your app from the device!?

Comment: @greenapps. No. It is just the installation.

Answer (score 2):

as long as the file is a part of your "assets" folder, it will be apart of your apk and there for you will have to pay the upload time.

you can reduce the apk upload time by removing the large files from your asset folder and getting them from somewhere else.

for example, you can use [android expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) for that purpose.

if you have to use it in assets folder, you can create a special "debug" apk:
special apk will not have the file in its assets, it will load the file from local storage. you can use adb to push the large file to the device. this way you will only load the file once to device and save precious debug time.

Comment: What do you mean by special "debug" apk that will not have the assets file in it? how to create that special file?

Comment: 1. remove the file from the assets folder      2.upload that file to the device, e.g /mnt/sdcard/MyFile          3.in your code, load the file from /mnt/sdcard/ instead from assets. this is of course should only be used while DEBUGING